# Creating a variable like x = func(); function call and var creation order defined?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

```
void f()
{
    auto x = func();
    int y = func();
    auto z = f1() * f2() + static_cast<int>(f3());
}
```

I believe it should be defined that call to the `func` will always happened first, before memory allocation for `x`, for the case with `auto`, but couldn't found info about it.

Is it so?
And is it defined for the case when type is explicitly written?

Comment: x is allocated first, then the function is called.

Comment: @Surt and where it's written so?

Comment: Both (all three) are copy initialisation https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization and the variable is initialised with the result of the expression on the rhs.  No assignment takes place.

Comment: Depends on if its a function, then its on the stack, if its in a class the class must be created first, if its global it will be created in .BSS. If you give a context, function etc., you can see which of those it is.

Comment: You can use `&x` in its own initialization, so it has to be allocated first.

Comment: if `func` returns `int` then there is no difference between `int x = func();` and `auto x = func();`

Comment: Memory allocation for `x` is not an observable side effect, so it's not clear what "happens first" even means here. Why does it matter, what difference would it make? What is the real problem you are trying to solve, that you believe an answer to this question would bring you closer to the solution?

Comment: If by "evaluation of `auto` type" you mean type deduction, then it happens at compile time, not at run time - so of course before the program runs, before any functions are called, and before any memory is allocated. I sense some misconception here.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik _What is the real problem you are trying to solve_ Always feel weird when see such comment below a language-lawyer tagged question. _If by "evaluation of auto type" you mean type deduction_ "evaluation of auto type" is invented by the question editor, not the author.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I must admit I haven't paid attention to the tags; nor researched the edit history (is one expected to, before commenting?). In any case, the question is not formulated in language-lawyerly terms, and frankly doesn't really make much sense (to me, anyhow). Perhaps it's mis-tagged.

Comment: There is no such step as 'creation of the variable'. Memory allocation for a static variable takes place at link or load time, and for a local variable at method entry time. Not during execution of this code. As to the rest, obviously the function has to be called before the assignment, not after it.

Comment: @user207421 and where can I read about it? All local variables are allocated at method entry time? If I have if () { int x= 2; /*some code*/ else { int y = 3; /*some code*/} both x and y will be allocated at method entry time?

Comment: @Surt I've edited the question a bit

Comment: The [tag:language-lawyer] was also added by the same editor that added the meaningless "when the evaluation of the auto type happens" phrase.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik for example if I'm measuring time, auto time_point = some_clock::now(); Then I'm using time_point for calculation say time difference. auto duration = start_point - time_point; would always be same as if I write auto duration = start_point - some_clock::now();?

Comment: @Johy: It is true that memory to hold local variables is usually allocated during the function prologue.  This is not the same as creating objects living in those variables.  And it is not the same as evaluating the initialization expression.  Moving the expression `some_clock::now()` around in the function will definitely change when the clock is read, even if it is read into memory storage that was allocated in the prologue.

Comment: @BenVoigt could you please  take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66960589/any-point-in-having-variable-for-end-time-for-time-measurment

Comment: @Johy: In your linked question, the thing you need to worry about is not whether there is an end variable or when its memory starts to exist, but whether the compiler can do some or all of the `accumulate` work before `some_clock::now()` is called the first time, or after it is called the second time.  The volatile write to `sink` prevents the second, to avoid the first you should write `sink = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), sink);`  That way the clock has to be read the first time before the volatile read of `sink`.

Comment: @Johy You can 'read about it' in the generated code. You won't find any instruction corresponding to the declaration. But you will find a stack probe or equivalent of the new top of the stack including the calling sequence and local stack frame, in the prologue. You won't find this stuff in the language specification because it is implementation-dependent. You might if seriously interested have a look at Lippman, *Inside the C++ Object Model.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluation of the initialization expression (`func()` or `f1() * f2() + static_cast<int>(f3())`) definitely happens only when the particular line of code is reached.<sup>1</sup>

Memory for the variable may be obtained (aka "allocation") at any time earlier... however there's no way to use that memory prior to the definition because until the definition is reached there's no way to name that memory.  The variable name is introduced into scope by the definition.

The lifetime of the object living in the variable doesn't begin until the initializer is fully evaluated and placed<sup>2</sup> into the new object.  See [`[basic.life]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1):

> The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when:
>
> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained, and
> - its initialization (if any) is complete (including vacuous initialization)

If the address of the variable is never taken, the variable might not need any memory at all (it could fit in a CPU register for its entire lifetime).

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, under the as-if rule, the compiler can move it around so long as you can't tell the difference.  Unless you have undefined behavior such as a data race, it will always act exactly like the computation is done when reaching that line of code.

<sup>2</sup> For the copy-initialization syntax used in the question, old versions of C++ generally required a copy or move, while newer versions mandate in-place construction via copy-elision.

Comment: Memory for the variable may be obtained (aka "allocation") at any time earlier. -- so it's never the case that expression (maybe partly) on the right side is evaluated before left side variable was allocated? It's defined somewhere in the standard?

Comment: @Johy: "May" is permission, not a requirement.  It's hard to really pin down things which aren't a separate step.  For example, a function prologue adjusts the stack pointer once making room for a dozen local variables, some of which may share storage if their lifetimes don't overlap.  Storage for a variable which is enregistered starts to exist right after the last other thing stops using that register.